# How to change the information on another page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am making a shopping bag for a store, which inputs the number of items in cart(using incrementing whenever add to cart button is clicked), However I would like this number to stay on all my pages(Home page, shop now page and etc.) but the information only stays in one page and even changes on refresh. Is there a way that the incremented number could be transferred to my other pages?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried and what is not working.

Comment: If the user is navigating to different pages (that is, if this isn't a single-page-app) then any information you want to save would have to be saved somewhere.  Local storage, a session cookie, posted to a server, etc.

Comment: I don't know what to try, I am new to IT so I need some serious help

Comment: You could use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or more recently [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) for this purpose.